# PySimpleGUI : Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.1.1.dll

Tags: python, pysimplegui

After compiling my python program into .exe file using PySimpleGUI, I got error "Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.1.dll"

[image]

Figure below are all the packages in my virtual environtment
[image]
[image]

I've tried many possible answer that I could find, but the issue still persist.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: try `pyinstaller --add-binary your_dll.dll;. your_script.py`

Comment: thank you for your response. Where can I get mkl_intel_thread.1.dll file? I noticed in my Anaconda directory, I only have this mkl_intel_thread.dll (without 1).

Comment: Not sure where the file located, search file in your drivers. Try `mkl_intel_thread.dll` if still not found.

Comment: well I got that file named mkl_intel_thread.dll, but the error said mkl_intel_thread.1.dll (with 1). Are they the same file?

Comment: I didn't use any library depend on that DLL file, and there's no code to show what library you used. So I have no answer for you about where the file.

Comment: Library that I used geopandas (dependencies: pandas, numpy, shapely, gdal, pyproj)

Comment: Well thank you, after searching for a while, I finally able to get the file somewhere in the Anaconda directory and I added it using --add-binary parameter and I know I got a new eror https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865273/pyinstaller-fiona-has-no-attribute-loading-most-likely-due-to-a-circular