# Pyinstaller: 'Fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, geopandas, pysimplegui, fiona

I really need help dealing with this issue.

I run my script on PyScripter and everything works perfectly, but when I try to bundle all the scripts into .exe using PyInstaller I got an error as shown in the picture below.
[image]

I also try to run from the Anaconda prompt in my virtual environment, there is no issue at all.

How can I fix this issue??

FYI, I also provide my conda information.
[image]

and all the packages that I used.
[image]

Plus, a snippet from my code (I don't know whether it's relevant or not)
[image]

The figure below should be the output that I look for
[image]

Thank you for your help, it's been many days and I still couldn't fix this issue.

Comment: Try PyInstaller 4.1 or 3.9.

Comment: Well, okay I will try to install that version. What's the big deal with downgrade to that version? Thank you

Comment: I've met an issue that is not able to pack `frozendict` in PyInstaller 4.3 but works well on 3.9 and 4.1. I'm not sure if you hit the similar issue since you only fail after packing.

Comment: Please edit information that is textual into your question __as text__ i.e. NOT as images.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this gonna solve your problem, but you can try my method.
I directly change the code from fiona's `__init__` file.

```
import fiona._loading 
with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
```

to

```
import _loading
with _loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cx_freeze instead of pyinstaller, it worked for me.